# Web Platform Installer on Windows XP. IIS still crippled?

Tags: iis, windows-xp, web-platform-installer

I am pondering using the Web Platform Installer to quickly set up a dev environment in Windows XP.

Will the IIS installed by the Web Platform Installer still have the 40 connection limit applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Web Platform Installer doesn't include IIS. It just asks for your OS installation media and installs IIS from that. However, you might get some benefit from [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx).

Comment: This question pre-dated the announcement of IIS Express, but thanks for the clarification anyway